# Include JSP page

Tags: jsp, jspinclude

I have a JSP code that is used in several forms, and i'm trying to include it inside of a JSP page.

It works fine with static JSP, but i did not succeed with dynamic JSP.

The code i'm trying to include is something like that:

```
<ui:panelLayout id="panelMem" panelLayout="flow" >
            <p>TestMem</p>
            <ui:label id="labelTest" style="left: 24px; top: 0px; position: absolute" text="TEST"/>          
</ui:panelLayout>
```

And i tried jsp:include and jsp:directive:include, but it doesn't work.

Finally, the tags of my application are:

```
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui">
```

Unfortunately, i can't change the application. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: In which way it doesn't work? Are you getting any error?

Comment: The "<p>TestMem</p>" is rendered. The label "labelTest" is not rendered. If i try: <ui:label binding="#{Beans$Bean1.lblTest}" id="labelTest" text="Memtest2"/> got a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: The tags you are using are also included in the jsp you want to include??

Comment: Yes, they are included in both jsp.

Comment: When you use `<jsp:include>` you must pass as arguments the variables used inside the included JSP with `<jsp:param>`. Are you passing them?

Comment: Ehm... actually not. But, i don't use any variable in the first label ("labelTest").

Comment: Finally i got it working. It was a problem with the format of the component, and the id given. Thanks for your replies at all.